# Serving MQTT over WebSocket in Kubernates GCP environment

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm currently serving MQTT messages over WebSocket to js clients. I use RabbitMQ to write messages on queue from a java backend and have them routed to the clients/frontend apps.
I deployed everything on a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform and everything works just fine as long as I publish the RabbitMQ pod with a Kubernetes Load Balancer directly to the internet.

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http-manager
    nodePort: 30019
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15672
  - name: mqtt-broker
    nodePort: 31571
    port: 1883
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1883
  - name: ws-service
    nodePort: 32048
    port: 15675
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15675
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
```

I try to replace the Kubernetes Load balancer with a Node port service and expose it through an Ingress and a GCP Balancer but the health probe fails and never recovers.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
  name: rabbitmq-internal
spec:
  ports:
  - name: ws-port
    port: 15675
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15675
  - name: mamanger-port
    port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort


apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basictest
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mqtt-host.dom.cloud
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: rabbitmq-internal
          servicePort: 15675
        path: /ws/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: rabbitmq-internal
          servicePort: 15672
        path: /*
```

The probe is HTTP so I tried to assign a custom TCP probe and even to trick GCP switching with a probe that points to another HTTP port on the same pod, with no success.

I need to user GCP Balancer to have a unified frontend to assign an SSL Certificate for both HTTPS and WSS protocols.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about the ingress configuration as I assume that when you are using Service type load balancer, it works however when you change it to ingress then it get failed (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Thanks, do you think the question is more clear now?

Comment: Are you able  to reach external TrafficPolicy(endpoint)? I mean is traffic go to a pod on the same node? Also, check the deployment which is serving and how many replica configured? If there is no pod, then there will be no instance that is healthy which is expected behavior. You can some find useful information [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/).

Comment: I can reach the externa traffic policy ( it is the current solution that I would like to improve ) The deployment has one replica which is healthy ( considering its own healthy probe aka HTTP GET on port 15672 ). The load balancer works fine is the GCP Network balancer that is giving me problems

Comment: Due to the complex nature of this issue, we need to do more investigation. I would suggest you to report this issue via Public Issue Tracker [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491576&template=1161385). so, we can narrow down the issue in private mode over there.